# Better gradient descent implementation for linear SVM with varying loss?

Tags: machine-learning, julia, svm, gradient-descent

I'm implementing SVM with hinge loss (linear SVM, soft margin), and try to minimize the loss using gradient descent.
Here's my current gradient descent, in Julia:

```
for i in 1:max_iter
    if n_cost_no_change <= 0 && early_stop
        break
    end
    learn!(X_data, Y_data, weights, learning_rate) # compute gradient and update weights
    new_cost = cost(X_data, Y_data, weights) # compute loss
    if early_stop
        if best_cost === nothing || isnan(best_cost)
            best_cost = new_cost
        else
            if new_cost > best_cost - tol
                n_cost_no_change -= 1
            else
                best_cost = min(new_cost, best_cost)
                n_cost_no_change = n_iter_no_change
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here, `tol` is set to 0.001, `max_iter` is 1000, `learning_rate` is 0.05, and they are all constant during training.

The problem is that the computed `cost` for each iteration is varying a lot.
In order to force finding a global minimum, I have to turn off `early_stop` and set `max_iter` to 10000.
Otherwise, it will stop early within few iterations, and output a bad result.

Here's a graph showing how `cost` vary by iterations:
[image]

These iterations are just waste of time.

My guess is that I also need to change my `learning_rate` each iteration if there's no improvement on the `cost`.
The problem is that I don't know how to implement an update to `learning_rate` in a way such that the variance on `cost` is reduced and I won't fall into a local minimum (if it exists), and find the optimal weights for linear SVM.

Anyone has any suggestions?

### update

Here's my `learn!` function:

```
function learn!(X_data::Array{T} where T<:Number, Y_data::Array{T} where T<:Number, weights::WeightsLinearSVM, alpha::AbstractFloat)
    @assert ndims(Y_data) == ndims(weights.w) == 1
    @assert size(X_data) == (size(Y_data)[1], size(weights.w)[1])
    # compute deciding feature
    decide = (Y_data .* (X_data * weights.w .+ weights.b)) .< 1 # (? < 1) will be 1, otherwise 0
    # update w
    gradient_w = weights.w .+ (weights.C / size(X_data)[1]) .* vec(-(Y_data .* decide)' * X_data)
    gradient_w .= gradient_w .* alpha
    weights.w .= weights.w .- gradient_w
    # update b
    gradient_b = (weights.C / size(X_data)[1]) * sum(-(Y_data .* decide))
    gradient_b *= alpha
    weights.b = weights.b - gradient_b
    return nothing
end
```

`cost` function:

```
function cost(X_data::Array{T} where T<:Number, Y_data::Array{T} where T<:Number, weights::WeightsLinearSVM)::AbstractFloat
    @assert ndims(Y_data) == ndims(weights.w) == 1
    @assert size(X_data) == (size(Y_data)[1], size(weights.w)[1])
    loss_w = 0.5 * (weights.w' * weights.w)
    loss_inner = 1.0 .- Y_data .* vec(X_data * weights.w .+ weights.b)
    loss_inner .= map(m->max(0.0,m), loss_inner)
    loss = loss_w + weights.C * sum(loss_inner) / size(X_data)[1]
    return loss
end
```

Comment: Often this kind of oscillatory behaviour is caused by a too large step size. But your curve looks like the peaks are _exactly_ repeating, that's strange. I guess you should also include the code for `learn!`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [article](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#momentum), I tried to use a momentum on gradient update.

My new `learn!` function looks like this:

```
function learn!(X_data::Array{T} where T<:Number, Y_data::Array{T} where T<:Number, weights::WeightsLinearSVM, momentum::WeightsLinearSVM, alpha::AbstractFloat)
    @assert ndims(Y_data) == ndims(weights.w) == 1
    @assert size(X_data) == (size(Y_data)[1], size(weights.w)[1])
    # compute deciding feature
    decide = (Y_data .* (X_data * weights.w .+ weights.b)) .< 1 # (? < 1) will be 1, otherwise 0
    # update w
    gradient_w = weights.w .+ (weights.C / size(X_data)[1]) .* vec(-(Y_data .* decide)' * X_data)
    gradient_w .= gradient_w .* alpha
    momentum.w .= gradient_w .+ (0.9 .* momentum.w)
    weights.w .= weights.w .- momentum.w
    # update b
    gradient_b = (weights.C / size(X_data)[1]) * sum(-(Y_data .* decide))
    gradient_b *= alpha
    momentum.b = gradient_b + (0.9 * momentum.b)
    weights.b = weights.b - momentum.b
    return nothing
end
```

Here is a comparison on the cost oscillation.

Before using momentum:
[image]

After using momentum:
[image]

I'm satisfied with the improvement. Probably will try other optimization algorithms mentioned in the article as well.